# Automatically cancel orders after 30 minutes when payment is not completed

Tags: orders, order-state

We have integrated the CCAvenue payment module. Some time customer not complete the payment. So the product stock decreased in the product table at submit the order. We need to cancel the order with stock added the relevant products for the order.

How to implement this?

Comment: have you use Cancal button at Admin

Comment: Simply cancel your order from backend.

Comment: We need to automatically cancel the order after order 30 min

Comment: write a cron job which will run every 30 minutes and get the orders which is not done payment and set the status to cancel.

Comment: Is there any cron url or need to create a new file? If you have any coding for please post the code

Comment: no url.u need to create a function in which all non payment orders will get cancel and u need to run this function using the cron

Comment: No need to Curl...

Comment: Ok. How to get the order of Payment pending order?

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume you know how to create a new extension.

Add a new cronjob in the file `config.xml` of your extension:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <!--  ... rest your extension configuration ... -->    
    <crontab>
        <jobs>
            <cancel_pending_orders>
                <schedule>
                    <cron_expr>0,30 * * * *</cron_expr>
                </schedule>
                <run>
                    <model>your_module/cron::cancelPendingOrders</model>
                </run>
            </cancel_pending_orders>
        </jobs>
    </crontab>           
</config>
```

Then create `Your_Module_Model_Cron` with this code:

```
<?php

class Your_Module_Model_Cron
{

    /**
     * @param Mage_Cron_Model_Schedule $schedule
     * @return Your_Module_Model_Cron
     */
    public function cancelPendingOrders($schedule)
    {
        foreach ($this->getCollection() as $order) {
            if (!$order->canCancel()) {
                continue;
            }
            $order->cancel();
            $order->save(); 
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order_Collection
     */
    public function getCollection()
    {
        // You could make this configurable in the backend
        $minutes = 30;

        // If necessary, you can filter the collection by other criteria like order state/status, payment method etc.
        $collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToFilter('state', Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PENDING_PAYMENT)
            ->addFieldToFilter('created_at', array('lt' => new Zend_Db_Expr("DATE_SUB('" . Mage::getModel('core/date')->gmtDate() . "', INTERVAL " . $minutes . " MINUTE)")));

        return $collection;
    }
}
```

What I didn't do but what you may want to do is wrap the order save in a transaction.